# Do all Go functions return err as second return value?

Tags: go

I see code snippets were functions return `err` as last argument a lot of time.

```
f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(asciiFloat, 64)
```

Question is must all functions be made to return err even if no error handling is involved in the function implementation.
And how will I know a function is or is not returning an `err` value?

Must I checkout docs every time I need to use a function?

Comment: What kind of searching have you done to answer this yourself? The answer is pretty obviously "no" if you spend even a few seconds searching.

Comment: Of course you should read the docs of a function at least once before using it. How else would you know what it does?

Comment: "Must I checkout docs every time I need to use a function?" Is this some kind of trick question? Or are you in a time zone where it is still April 1st?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely need to read the documentation for the functions you use. Otherwise you'll end up opening a lot of questions that could have been answered faster by reading the docs. For example, the [first demonstration of functions in the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/4) shows that you don't always have to return an error.

Comment: `strconv.ParseFloat()` absolutely can return errors. It is not guaranteed to be successful. It depends on what input it received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answering your question:*
Fortunately, Go prevents certain types of programmers errors. It just won't let you compile the program if you forget one of the values that the function returns.

It's a good practice to return errors in Go, read **Errors** section of [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#errors)

> Library routines must often return some sort of error indication to the caller. As mentioned earlier, Go's multivalue return makes it easy to return a detailed error description alongside the normal return value. It is good style to use this feature to provide detailed error information.

and [Error handling and Go](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)

> In Go, error handling is important. The language's design and conventions encourage you to explicitly check for errors where they occur

However there is a problem described [here](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-error-handling-overview.md) and probably will be improved in Go 2

> In general Go programs have too much code checking errors and not enough code handling them.

Dave Cheney writes in [the blog](http://%3Ehttps://dave.cheney.net/2019/01/27/eliminate-error-handling-by-eliminating-errors)

> I’m suggesting changing your code so you don’t have as many errors to handle.

Answer (score 2):

> must all functions be made to return err

No.

But in case you function may return error - you have to return this error as last value.

It's good practice to return error as last value.

> how will I know a function is or is not returning an err

Before using some function you have to see that function and in declaration you'll see what function returns. Also it's good to read documentation to function, and check out how to use function.

Comment: It's more than good practice, it's (loosely) enforced by the standard linter.

Comment: what happens if incorrectly capture an `err` value from function that returns non

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic You'll get error `assignment mismatch: 2 variables but 1 values`, like: https://play.golang.org/p/VLZvceokqfJ